# MVC 5 Razor Url.Content(null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I've for this mvc5 razor code that is giving error

```
 <img class="img-rounded thumbnail-upload" src="@Url.Content(@Model.ImageThumbSrc)" />
```

The error is `Object cannot be null or empty` when `Model.ImageThumbSrc == null`

I need to be able to display `src=""` when `Model.ImageThumbSrc == null`

I tried several ways with `??` and `@{ }` but cannot get razor syntax to compile.

How can I get this to work? This should be simple but I just cant get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a code block to create a temporary variable and use it:

```
@{
    var imageSource = Model.Question == null ? "" : Url.Content(Model.Question);
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<img class="img-rounded thumbnail-upload" src="@imageSource" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this inlne version:

```
<img class="img-rounded thumbnail-upload" src="@(Model.ImageThumbSrc == null ? "" : Url.Content(Model.ImageThumbSrc))" />
```